# LastIndexOf in Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to implement a function in a Windows batch script to get the LastIndexOf a character into a given string.

For example: Given the following string, I need to get the last index of character `'/'`:

```
/name1/name2/name3
            ^
```

So I need to get the value:

```
12
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Note: I'm assuming Windows batch files because, frankly, I have only seen a single question asking for an* actual *DOS batch file here so far. Most people simply misattribute “DOS” to anything that has a window of gray-on-black monospaced text without knowing what they're actually talking of.)*

Just loop through it, updating the index as you go:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set S=/name1/name2/name3
set I=0
set L=-1
:l
if "!S:~%I%,1!"=="" goto ld
if "!S:~%I%,1!"=="/" set L=%I%
set /a I+=1
goto l
:ld
echo %L%
```

Comment: The code works ok, but I created a function using your code, the function prints the result, but never returns, do you know why? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since I don't see your code I don't have an idea why it doesn't return. I know why it prints the result, though: You still have the `echo` in there. As to why it doesn't return I can only guess. My guess would be that you didn't write a function and just called a label with `goto` instead of `call :label`.

Comment: +1; a simple straight forward solution, though relatively slow.

Comment: It's probably faster to start from the last character and breaking early, but that would require knowing the length of the string (which itself needs 17 iterations, if I remember correctly). Although batch files and speed optimisation are probably terms that don't like each other very much, anyway :D

Answer (score 9):

Joey's solution works, but the character to find is hard coded, and it is relatively slow.

Here is a parametized function that is fast and can find any character (except nul) within the string. I pass the name of variables containing the string and the character instead of string literals so that the function easily supports all characters.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "test=/name1/name2/name3"
set "char=/"

::1st test simply prints the result
call :lastIndexOf test char

::2nd test stores the result in a variable
call :lastIndexOf test char rtn
echo rtn=%rtn%

exit /b

:lastIndexOf  strVar  charVar  [rtnVar]
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

  :: Get the string values
  set "lastIndexOf.char=!%~2!"
  set "str=!%~1!"
  set "chr=!lastIndexOf.char:~0,1!"

  :: Determine the length of str - adapted from function found at:
  :: http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.strLen
  set "str2=.!str!"
  set "len=0"
  for /L %%A in (12,-1,0) do (
    set /a "len|=1<<%%A"
    for %%B in (!len!) do if "!str2:~%%B,1!"=="" set /a "len&=~1<<%%A"
  )

  :: Find the last occurrance of chr in str
  for /l %%N in (%len% -1 0) do if "!str:~%%N,1!" equ "!chr!" (
    set rtn=%%N
    goto :break
  )
  set rtn=-1

  :break - Return the result if 3rd arg specified, else print the result
  ( endlocal
    if "%~3" neq "" (set %~3=%rtn%) else echo %rtn%
  )
exit /b
```

It wouldn't take much modification to create a more generic `:indexOf` function that takes an additional argument specifying which occurance to find. A negative number could specify to search in reverse. So 1 could be the 1st, 2 the 2nd, -1 the last, -2 penultimate, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a bit old now, but I needed a function that could find the location of a substring (of any length) within a string, and adapted dbenham's solution for my purposes.  This function also works with individual characters within a string, as asked for in the original question, and can search for specific instances (as suggested by dbenham).

To use this function, the actual strings must be passed.  Dbenham does note that this supports fewer characters than passing the actual variables, but I find that this variant is more reuseable (especially with pipes).

The third argument takes the instance that should be found, with negative numbers specifying to search from the end.  The index returned is the offset from the start of the string to the first character in the substring.

```
@ECHO off
SET search_string=sub
CALL :strIndex "The testing subjects subjects to testing." "%search_string%" -2
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
PAUSE
EXIT

:strIndex string substring [instance]
    REM Using adaptation of strLen function found at http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeCmdLib.php#Function.strLen

    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
    IF "%~2" EQU "" SET Index=-1 & GOTO strIndex_end
    IF "%~3" EQU "" (SET Instance=1) ELSE (SET Instance=%~3)
    SET Index=-1
    SET String=%~1

    SET "str=A%~1"
    SET "String_Length=0"
    FOR /L %%A IN (12,-1,0) DO (
        SET /a "String_Length|=1<<%%A"
        FOR %%B IN (!String_Length!) DO IF "!str:~%%B,1!"=="" SET /a "String_Length&=~1<<%%A"
    )
    SET "sub=A%~2"
    SET "Substring_Length=0"
    FOR /L %%A IN (12,-1,0) DO (
        SET /a "Substring_Length|=1<<%%A"
        FOR %%B IN (!Substring_Length!) DO IF "!sub:~%%B,1!"=="" SET /a "Substring_Length&=~1<<%%A"
    )

    IF %Substring_Length% GTR %String_Length% GOTO strIndex_end

    SET /A Searches=%String_Length%-%Substring_Length%
    IF %Instance% GTR 0 (
        FOR /L %%n IN (0,1,%Searches%) DO (
            CALL SET StringSegment=%%String:~%%n,!Substring_Length!%%

            IF "%~2" EQU "!StringSegment!" SET /A Instance-=1
            IF !Instance! EQU 0 SET Index=%%n & GOTO strIndex_end
    )) ELSE (
        FOR /L %%n IN (%Searches%,-1,0) DO (
            CALL SET StringSegment=%%String:~%%n,!Substring_Length!%%

            IF "%~2" EQU "!StringSegment!" SET /A Instance+=1
            IF !Instance! EQU 0 SET Index=%%n & GOTO strIndex_end
    ))

:strIndex_end
    EXIT /B %Index%
```